# batch compress all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Running into a problem with the code below.  I'm trying to batch compress all tables in a certain database, but there's an issue with my syntax...

```
USE backups
GO

DECLARE @tables TABLE ( TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(MAX) )

INSERT INTO @tables ( TABLE_NAME ) SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES

WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM @tables ) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table VARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM @tables )

    DELETE FROM @tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table

    BEGIN TRY
        ALTER TABLE @table REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE )
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RAISERROR( 'Compression failed for backup table : %s', 20, 101, @table ) WITH LOG
    END CATCH
END
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Incorrect syntax near '@table'.  Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I found that you can't use variable names for tables or other schema objects in some situations.  This fixes the problem...

```
USE backups
GO

DECLARE @tables TABLE ( TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX) )
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

INSERT INTO @tables ( TABLE_NAME ) SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES

WHILE ( SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM @tables ) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @table VARCHAR(MAX) = ( SELECT TOP 1 TABLE_NAME FROM @tables )

    DELETE FROM @tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table

    BEGIN TRY
        SET @query = N'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + N' REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH ( DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE )'

        EXEC sp_executesql @query
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        RAISERROR( 'Compression failed for backup table : %s', 20, 101, @table ) WITH LOG
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a slight update in line 3 by adding `where TABLE_TYPE= 'BASE TABLE'` at the end, so the full line 3 looks like:

```
INSERT INTO @tables ( TABLE_NAME ) SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE= 'BASE TABLE'
```